# Are there any man pages that summarize bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, manpage, info

I have a computer science test coming up on basic bash scripting. We work on offline-only linux machines (pretty much stock Fedora) that have all the typical man/info pages installed. That being said, memorizing things like bash `if` statement tests and stuff is quite monotonous, is there a man/info page that covers simple topics like `if` syntax, bash script syntax, etc.?

Comment: For `if` check `man test`. For bash in general, `man bash`. And the main bash reference is http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: man test :o that's exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: look http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_01.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The description of bash syntaxes like `if` statements or `for` loop is in the command `help`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if man pages are very handy I would recommend you to use simple tutorial-like pages. These are some:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

They cover the most basic and simple things you should know.

Comment: I have tons of online resources available to me, I'm just looking for offline man pages that are typical to linux machines.

Comment: Every command should have a man page. You could enter here: http://ss64.com/bash/ and note down de most important commands or topics that you are studying. The is just "man noted_command" and you should get its related info.

Comment: However, you could always look for a "cheatsheet", which covers with tiny information, a wide range of commands and syntax for an specific language. For example: http://nomikos.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/bash_cheat_sheet.png